# controlling position of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am attempting to control the position of a boxed insert created using the `tcolorbox` package.  However I cannot fully control the position of the box as for figures and tables, for example using for example `htpb!`.  Here is an example that replicates the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\begin{tcolorbox}[float=htpb!, title=A box]
    This is a box!\\
    With a couple lines.
\end{tcolorbox}
Some more text. 
\end{document}
```

I would like the box to appear before "some more text."

Comment: Do you really need the floating of the box?

Comment: Just remove the `float=htpb!`, and the box will appear exactly where you put it in the code.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to let this box to float around (I never needed it for `tcolorbox` yet). Just remove the `float` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=A box]
    This is a box!\\
    With a couple lines.
\end{tcolorbox}

Some more text. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks...this works for my MWE but not for my more complex real example.  In the real example I have the sequence: table 1, figure, table 2, box, and the box appears after table 1 no matter what I have tried (including this suggestion).  I'm not sure if that's enough information...I will try to come up with a MWE that fully captures the issue

Comment: @tvg: Of course, your other tables and figures are floating away then -- and you're changing the question now

Comment: truth.  trying to figure out the real problem...